# JBoss cache & Hiberate 4.x, is it possible?

Tags: hibernate, caching, jboss, infinispan

I'm trying to get JBoss cache working with Hibernate 4.1.9, but there is no documentation or indication that it is even possible, anymore. No notes on why not either, if so. I used it successfully for Hibernate 3.x.

Any ideas?

It's mentioned here as a provider: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/

But not here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/

(manual vs. dev guide...)

Seems that some of the JBoss classes are removed from 4.

I know there's the later Infinispan, but for various reasons, that's not feasible right now.

Comment: You have to use infinispan for hibernate 4 second level cache, JBoss cache wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate 4 only supports Ehcache and Infinispan.
Infinispan is the evolution of JBoss Cache, that's why it started at version 4.0.
Regarding the other cache providers, they are all old and mostly unmaintained: nobody volunteered to update them to the new integration interface so they where dropped.

Thanks for spotting the documentation inconsistency:
https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-8044

Comment: Actually that was fixed already in the newer docs: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html_single/